# Getting Error `state does not match` intermittently when suing passport-ci-oidc library in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, ldap, passport.js

We are using passport-ci-oidc library in NODEJS for authenticating our users via Cloud Identity service.

We are seeing an intermittent issue while authentication with error...

```
  Error: state does not match
       at Strategy.authenticate (/media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/passport-ci-oidc/lib/strategy.js:359:23)
       at attempt (/media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
       at authenticate (/media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
       at exports.sso_callback (/media/cb-core-auth/authentication/passport-ibmidci/callback.js:77:7)
       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
       at next (/media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
       at Route.dispatch (/media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
       at /media/cb-core-auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

Can you guys please help us how to resolve this intermittent issue.

NOTE: We are not sending `state` as part of our Strategy.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue

Comment: Hey Lucifer007, @SDRP - Did you find any resolution for this issue? I'm also facing the same error using passport-ci-oidc npm plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error explaning that the state is supposed to be preserved in your session is supposed to match the state query param that comes back in the callback request from your OIDC provider.  Check your session information to make sure it's being kept on your server and the session cookie is being passed back

Answer (score 0):

@Lucifer007 @SDRP
I found the temp solution for this, it doesn't work because of the express session configuration that you may have. This config doesn't work with nginx proxy.

```
cookie: {
  secure: true
}
```

This was the reason in my case, commenting this line resolved my issue. Though not an ideal solution. Some other solution points to using cookie session instead of express session to solve this issue. Not tried, but seems to work.